# Oracle Apex Restrict Report Data based on Authorization schemes and roles

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an Apex IG with the employee data.

[image]

I also have roles and authorization schemes created.

Ex: For Sales Manager, Authorization scheme is USER_SALES_MANAGER.
Similarly for Marketing we have USER_MARKETING_MANAGER.

Requirement is that USER_SALES_MANAGER can only view rows with Dept as Sales.

Similarly USER_MARKETING_MANAGER can only view Dept as Marketing.

So data is to be restricted on basis of authorization.

How can this be achieved?

I cannot post entire and actual data due to restrictions. Even some idea or guidance would be great here.

Answer (score 1):

As you said: idea or guidance.

Let's presume that authorization scheme is based on a function which accepts `APP_USER` as a parameter and returns `1` if that user is a sales (or marketing) manager (and `0` otherwise).

Even if scheme isn't based on a function, then create one which does as described.

Then you'd modify query to reuse such a function in its `where` clause, using `case` expression:

```
select empid, empname, dept, bu, rank
from your_table
where dept = case when f_user_is_sales_manager     (:APP_USER) = 1 then 'Sales'
                  when f_user_is_marketing_manager (:APP_USER) = 1 then 'Marketing'
             end
```

Answer (score 1):

Data striping based on auth schemes isn't very straightforward in APEX. One solution is to base your auth schemes on functions as @Littlefoot describes but another option is to use application items for that.

Create one application item per auth scheme. Let's take the one for auth scheme "USER_SALES_MANAGER" as example.

- Create Application item `F_IS_SALES_MANAGER`
- Add and application computations for `F_IS_SALES_MANAGER`. "Type Function Body", Computation Point "On New Instance", Source:

```
RETURN 
  CASE WHEN APEX_AUTHORIZATION.IS_AUTHORIZED ('USER_SALES_MANAGER') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

- Query source (assuming you created 2 application items as described above):

```
select empid, empname, dept, bu, rank
from your_table
where dept = case when :F_IS_SALES_MANAGER = 1 then 'Sales'
                  when :F_IS_MARKETING_MANAGER = 1 then 'Marketing'
             end
```

Comment: Thank you Koen, this worked beautifully in my APEX app!